# Relação entre as tabelas laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel

Gostaria de uma sugestão de como implementar relação entre tabelas no laravel utilizando migration.

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('professors', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('id_professor');
        $table->string('nome');
        $table->string('data_nascimento');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('id_curso');
        $table->string('nome');
        $table->string('id_professor');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('id_aluno');
        $table->string('nome');
        $table->string('data_nascimento');
        $table->string('logradouro');
        $table->string('numero');
        $table->string('bairro');
        $table->string('cidade');
        $table->string('estado');
        $table->string('cep');
        $table->string('id_curso');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: O que você quer especificamente? Não ficou muito claro. Edite a pergunta e adicione mais informações.

Comment: `id_professor` para que se você já tem `id`?  Você pretende ter duas chaves primarias pra uma mesma tabela?

Comment: Queria perguntar como posso relacionar as tabelas nas linhas id_curso, id_professor.

Comment: Edite a pergunta e coloque essas informações, que assim eu poderia responder pra você.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá

Penso que é isto que queres, vê o método foreign() da Blueprint

Verifica a documentação em https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('professors', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('id_professor');
        $table->string('nome');
        $table->string('data_nascimento');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('id_curso');
        $table->string('nome');
        $table->string('id_professor');


        $table->foreign('id_professor')->references('id_professor')->on('professors');


        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('id_aluno');
        $table->string('nome');
        $table->string('data_nascimento');
        $table->string('logradouro');
        $table->string('numero');
        $table->string('bairro');
        $table->string('cidade');
        $table->string('estado');
        $table->string('cep');
        $table->string('id_curso');


        $table->foreign('id_curso')->references('id_curso')->on('courses');


        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: Sim, acabei de da uma olhada na documentação.Grato.